# WebDriver Firefox driver doesn't work

Tags: c#, firefox, webdriver

I'm using selenium webdriver 2.42.0, Firefox 29, C# and trying to create firefox driver

```
FirefoxProfile fp = new FirefoxProfile();

driver = new FirefoxDriver(new FirefoxBinary("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla    Firefox\\firefox.exe"), fp);
```

I see a new Firefox window and get WebDriverException

```
 Failed to start up socket within 45000 ms. Attempted to connect to the following addresses: 127.0.0.1:7055
```

Everything works fine with ChromeDriver and IE driver. The only advise I found is to check FF and selenium versions, but as I know FF29 and webdriver 2.42 should work together.
I'm also tried to use FF27, 28, 30, nothing works.

Comment: Are you trying to use a proxy or tor with it as well?

Comment: just kill all firefox & java sessions and then give a try.

Comment: Please re-word the question. Your code isn't compiling and has nothing to do with how well WebDriver works with Firefox. As worded, people will read this issue expecting to find a completely different question.

Answer (score -2):

Upgrade your selenium to newer version. If you use Maven Visit https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java